# Presentation component input not responding to toggle of observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two components in this demo.  The `ViewComponent` assigns an observable `isSelectedBookInCollection$` to the detail component like this:

```
  template: `<bc-book-detail 
                [book]="book" 
                [inCollection]="isSelectedBookInCollection$ | async"
                (add)="toggleCollection()"
                (remove)="toggleCollection()"></bc-book-detail>`,
```

When I click the `addBookToCollection` button the `isSelectedBookInCollection$` observable does fire with the right value, but it's not being picked up by the detail component's `@input`.

This is a stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-temp-slice-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fview-book.component.ts

The method:

```
  toggleCollection() {
    this.bookCollection.toggle(this.book);
    this.isSelectedBookInCollection$.subscribe(v=>console.log(v));
  }
```

Is what does toggle the `isSelectedBookInCollection$` which can be seen in the console.

Anyone see why the input `[inCollection]` input is not being updated?

### Stackblitz with Answer

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-temp-slice-demo-phase2?file=src/app/books/view-book.component.ts

Comment: As per your code isSelectedBookInCollection$ will get new value only if activeBook$ gets new value which is listening to changes in bookStore not BookCollection.

Comment: Hmmm - It seems like you are right.  The strange thing is that when clicking on the "Add Book To Collection" button, the ` isSelectedBookInCollection$` fires and we can see `true, false, true, false, etc.` in the console... so that part is a little strange.  I'm going to fork the demo and change the source of the observable to the collection.  Good observation - Thanks!

Comment: Yup you are 100% right - I changed it to observe the collection and now it works!  Thanks so much!!  This is a new stackblitz demo ... so that the only demo maintains the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-temp-slice-demo-phase2?file=src/app/books/view-book.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code `isSelectedBookInCollection$` will get new value only if `activeBook$` gets new value which is listening to changes in `bookStore` not `BookCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
 toggleCollection() {
    this.bookCollection.toggle(this.book);
    this.isSelectedBookInCollection$.subscribe(v=>{ return v;});
  }
```

[image]

Comment: That's just the part that I'm using to log what the value of `isSelectedBookInCollection$` is...the code ` this.bookCollection.toggle(this.book);` is what actually toggles the observable ... which should in turn update the `inCollection` input on the detail component ...The `async` pipe in the template should be performing the subscription for us.